# Nextjs Image component not rendering images in Safari

Tags: next.js, safari, render, nextjs-image

Setup:

nextjs v12.1

safari v13.1.2

node v14.19 (can adjust with nvm and have tried a few)

The problem is simple, but i cant figure out a solution.

I have multiple `<Image />` components in my nextjs project, and they render and work perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and Brave (havent tried IE)

But safari won't render them. It's weird because at some point, I was making some changes, nothing was helping, I reverted the changes and it rendered the images! i was wondering what i did! I naviated the site and came back to the main page with the images and once more they were not rendering.

Basic usage of the Image component looks like this

```
<Image
        src={'http://walldiskpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Waves-Abstract-Wallpaper.jpg'}                    
        height={240} width={500}
        layout={"responsive"}
/>
```

Again it works fine on firefox and chrome. Here are some screenshots of what i get on sources and network tab of safari

[image]
[image]

The sources tab shows that safari is unable to load any of the images... i dont know if it has to do with the base64. But I have seen them rendered at some point before i just dont know what is going on and i cant recreate it.

All this is in localhost by the way, i have not tested it online since i have yet to deploy.

Also by the way, this works fine on safari mobile! Im only having the issue in safari desktop

Answer (score -2):

Hey i was also looking for same issue found something

installing package next@canary solve it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: well i didnt try the canary, but i did deploy to server and navigated to the page on safari and it worked, so it only doesnt work on localhost for some reason... bizarre